# Equivalent SQL Query on Django ORM join table

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I want it to bring as a result the same rows as the .raw query does but using ORM. I ended up doing it using SQL because Django does not do JOINS with ORM and its not what ORM stands for. But i just want to try and see if any one can helpme improve this code.

thanks

```
query = '''SELECT
                quiniela_encuesta.id,
                quiniela_encuesta.golesEquipoA, 
                quiniela_encuesta.golesEquipoB, 
                quiniela_respuesta.equipoA, 
                quiniela_respuesta.equipoB

             FROM 
                quiniela_encuesta, 
                quiniela_respuesta

             WHERE
                quiniela_encuesta.id = quiniela_respuesta.encuesta_id
             AND
                quiniela_respuesta.empleado_id =  "%s" ''' % (idempleado) 

respuestas = respuesta.objects.raw(query)
```

my models.py is:

```
class equipo(models.Model):

nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
bandera = StdImageField(upload_to='bandera/%Y/%m/%d',
                        variations={
                        'large':(53,53, False),
                        'thumbnail': (70, 26, False)})

GRUPOS = (
    ('A', 'Grupo A'),
    ('B', 'Grupo B'),
    ('C', 'Gropo C'),
    ('D', 'Gropo D'),
    ('E', 'Gropo E'),
    ('F', 'Gropo F'),
    ('G', 'Gropo G'),
    ('H', 'Gropo H'),
)

grupo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GRUPOS)

def banderaEquipo(self):
    return '<img src="/media/%s">' % (self.bandera.thumbnail)

banderaEquipo.allow_tags = True

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre


class encuesta(models.Model):

equipoA = models.ForeignKey(equipo, related_name='equipo_equipoA')
golesEquipoA = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
equipoB = models.ForeignKey(equipo, related_name='equipo_equipoB')
golesEquipoB = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)

ETAPA = (
    ('1', 'Primera Etapa'),
    ('2', 'Octavos De Final'),
    ('3', 'Cuartos De Final'),
    ('4', 'Semifinal'),
    ('5', 'Final'),
    ('6', '3ra Posicion')
)

etapa = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ETAPA)
fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)

def __unicode__(self):

    return "%s Vs. %s" % (unicode(self.equipoA), unicode(self.equipoB))


class respuesta(models.Model):

encuesta = models.ForeignKey(encuesta)
empresa = models.ForeignKey(empresa)
empleado = models.ForeignKey(empleado)
equipoA = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
equipoB = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

def __unicode__(self):

    return "%s" % (unicode(self.encuesta))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `select_related` method to join tables. The tables will still be loaded in separate objects, but the following code will only execute a single query:

```
>>> respuestas = Respuesta.objects.select_related('encuesta')
>>> for respuesta in respuestas:
...     print respuesta.equipo_a
...     print respuesta.encuesta.goles_equipo_a 
        # respuesta.encuesta is already loaded due to a join
1
23
```

On a side note, I'd recommend adhering to the [PEP-8 naming conventions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) (particularly CamelCase for class names, lowercase_with_underscores for attributes). This will prevent accidentally hiding classes (e.g. when you use a variable called `respuesta`), and any other Python developer that would have to read your code will love you for it.